# Unable to implement asynchronous polling using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, completable-future, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to implement a polling functionality which does this:

```
while (condition is false or it does not timeout):
   call another end point
   wait(x seconds)
```

I wrote below code:

```
private static CompletableFuture<Integer> asyncStatusChecker() {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    CompletableFuture<Integer> completionFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    final ScheduledFuture<?> checkFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        int currentStatus = fetchStatus();
        System.out.println("current c: " + currentStatus);
        if (isStatusFinal(currentStatus)) {
            completionFuture.complete(currentStatus);
        }
    }, 5, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    completionFuture.whenComplete((result, thrown) ->
            checkFuture.cancel(true));
    completionFuture.orTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return completionFuture;
}
```

But it's not correct implementation as the process still remains active even after execution and also it does not look syntactically correct. Anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `isStatusFinal` a blocking call? You mean the `checkFuture` keeps running  even the `completionFuture`  has completed?

Comment: Yes, isStatusFinal is a blocking call. Yes, checkFuture keeps on running even after the process timesout or the isStatusFinal returns true

Comment: Should I ask how many times do you poll it in your code? I think you know that every time you poll, the function, it creates a new `ScheduledExecutorService` then a new `ScheduledFuture<?>` from it, and as well as a new `CompletableFuture<Integer>`, don't you? I think this is not intended one.  So I will suggest you to log the `checkFuture` object hash where you create and cancel it. If the hash codes are all same then the references of the previous created ones are all lost. Do it and let me know whether the hash codes are the same or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to update the status, like this:

```
    int currentStatus = fetchStatus();
    System.out.println("current c: " + currentStatus);
    if (isStatusFinal(currentStatus)) {
        completionFuture.complete(currentStatus);
    } else {
        //update status
    }
```

or do the update status thing at some otherwhere.